# how to cycle in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cycle

I have the code to retrieve the parameters from the photo. I would need to put it in the loop so it would load all of my photos from the folder and write them down in Python`enter code here

```
import requests

BASE_URL = 'https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect'
headers = {
  'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'd7264e9252674c9292b0d8b295cf3251',
  'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
}
parameters = {
  'returnFaceId': 'true',
  'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
  'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,emotion'
}

img_path = 'C:\\Users\\Pifko\\Desktop\\bakalarka\\subject13session2_Moment5up.jpg' 
img_data = open(img_path, 'rb').read()

def post_image(img_data):
    response = requests.post(BASE_URL, params=parameters,
                         headers=headers, data=img_data)
    try:
        return response.json()
    except:
        return None
    print(post_image(img_data))
```

Comment: Look into `for` and `while`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want `os.listdir`

```
for  fname in os.listdir(basepath):
     if fname[-3:] in ["jpg","gif","png"]:
        print("this is an image:",os.path.join(basepath,name))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get a list of all your files with a '.jpg' extension using:

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("/mydir")
for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    print(file)
```

You can put your code in a function and then call it for every file instead of the print statement.